# Python How to convert string with special characters into a dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to covert a string into a valid dict.

For example the string:

```
'{"value1":"\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1", "value2":"path c:\nord\tem\orme\test.exe"}'
```

I want to get a dict

```
{"value1":"\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1", 
 "value2":"path c:\nord\tem\norme\test.exe"}
```

How to convert this string into a dict without loosing spicial characters and without using backslash escape.

```
a_string = '{"value1":"\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1", "value2":"path c:\nord\tem\orme\test.exe"}'
a_dict = json.loads(a_string) # desired result a_dict = {"value1":"^stack.*/overflo\w$arr=1", "value2":"path c:\nord\tem\orme\test.exe"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the question. What is wrong with the result that you get from the example code?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, regular expression ("regex" for short) is not contextual grammar, thus it cannot differentiate whether an asterix ("*") inside pair of braces needs to be preserved, while others must be removed. Regex treats every character equally.

If the extra characters (here: asterixes) appear only at the beginning and at the end of json-like string, and you know that there are two of them on both ends, you can use slices to achieve your goal:

```
a_string = '**{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}**'
json_string = a_string[2:len(a_string)-2] # shortly: a_string[2:-2]
d = json.loads(json_string)
print(d)
#>>> {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Comment: Thanks, good point, but how to convert a string containing special  characters exemple (\n, \t , \*...) by keeping the same syntax (i.e. without escaping with backslash) ?

Comment: I don't understand. What happens when you try this code on a string "with special characters", and how is that different from what is supposed to happen? Just to make sure: you understand what if you type, for example, `"\n"` into your source code, that string does not actually have a backslash in it, correct? Do you *want* the corresponding result to have a backslash?

Comment: I have this error 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 12 (char 11)', I want these characters not to be interpreted but considered as str, I nee to have a dict with te some values as the str. Example a_string = '{"key":"path c:\nord\tem\orme\test.exe"}' => a_dict =  {"key":"path c:\nord\tem\orme\test.exe"}

Comment: you have to escape backslashes, using double backslash, you can do it per key-value pair in dict, but before JSON parser, like this...

    for key in dict.keys():
        d[key] = d[key].replace("\", "\\")

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator, something like this:

```py
original_String = "John - 10 , Rick - 20, Sam - 30" 

result = dict((a.strip(), int(b.strip()))  
                     for a, b in (element.split('-')  
                                  for element in original_String.split(', ')))
```

The original string is  `John - 10 , Rick - 20, Sam - 30`

The resultant dictionary is:  `{'John': 10, 'Rick': 20, 'Sam': 30}`

Answer (score -1):

if you can remove `**` of the first and end of the string you can use this standard python package to transform any string that is like a dictionary into a valid dictionary.

```py
>>> import ast
>>> a_string = r'{"value1":"\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1", "value2":"path c:\nord\tem\orme\test.exe"}'
>>> a_dict = ast.literal_eval(a_string)
>>> a_dict
{'value1': '\\^stack\\.\\*/overflo\\w\\$arr=1', 'value2': 'path c:\nord\tem\\orme\test.exe'}
```

python document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: Thank you, if you look at the a_dict in the a_dict['value1'] == '\\^stack\\.\\*/overflo\\w\\$arr=1', but what I want is to have the some str "\^stack\.\*/overflo\\w\$arr=1" without adding escape chara, some for a_dict['value2'] it was "path c:\nord\tem\orme\test.exe" but in your result it 'path c:\nord\tem\\orme\test.exe'